# Printing and concatenating a matrix

Tags: matlab

So I have a 16x5 matrix with numbers in each entry.

I want to print each row as such:

1&244&1&395&\$246,700\

So that I can copy and paste into latex without hurting my wrist. I have tried many things but nothing works. dlmwrite only allows me to use 1 delimiter. There doesn't need to be a comma in the last entry, I will do that manually if required, but I would at least like the rest.

Comment: There are 6 numbers: `1, 244,1,395,246,700`. Please clarify. Is `246700` a single number?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar: Yes, sorry. I add the comma in.

Comment: So is the `16x5` matrix actually `16x6`?  And did you mean to have a `\\\` at the end for a linebreak in LaTeX?

Comment: No, it's 16x5. I put a comma in to write a number 200000 like 200,000 so my audience can understand better. It's 16x5. And yes '\\' is for a linebreak in latex. I want to put this all right into a table in latex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more complicated printing schemes like this, I always go for [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html).
If your matrix is `A` with a `FileID` from [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html), you can get the output by

```
fprintf(FileID,'%d & %d & %d & %d & \\$%d,%d \\\\ \n',A);
```

More details on that format string can be [found here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0z60p-1).

---

Since the last number should a comma-separated value, you'll need to convert it to a string.
Here is a solution to the issue.
First, convert the last column into a column array of strings and use the function I wrote (not sure if one already exists):

```
Astr = num2strcomma(A(:,5));
```

That comma function is

```
function vstr = num2strcomma(v,varargin)

    nDigits = floor(log10(v)) ; 
    nCommas = floor(nDigits/3);

    vstr = cellstr(num2str(v,varargin{:}));
    for k = 1:length(vstr)
        nstr = vstr{k};
        ind  = 1:(length(nstr)+nCommas(k));
        work = repmat(' ',1,ind(end));
        start = find(nstr == '.',1);
        if isempty(start)
            start = ind(end);
        end
        indComma  = ind(start-3:-4:1);
        indNumber = setdiff(ind,indComma);
        work(indComma)  = ',';
        work(indNumber) = nstr;
        vstr{k} = work;
    end

end
```

Then loop through the array

```
for k = 1:size(A,1)
  fprintf(FileID,'%d & %d & %d & %d & \\$%s \\\\ \n',A(k,1:4),Astr{k});
end
```

Comment: I tried using this but whenever I try to use it I get:

>fprintf('test.txt','%d & %d & %d & %d & \$%d \n',A1)
test.txt>>

where I can type anything and it just does nothing.

Comment: The first argument should be a file identifier from `fopen`.  So you need to do `FileID = fopen('text.txt','w');` and then `fprintf(FileID,...`.

Comment: I've got this almost working but it won't print as I wish... hmm... doesn't like '\$' and '\\'. It also prints as 1 row sometimes.

Comment: The new edited format string should fix that (the double backslash will print a single backslash).  As for the 1 row problem, that would occur if the matrix doesn't have 6 columns, which is required for the six `%d` in the format string.

Comment: I have edited my answer to comma-seperate **integers**.  If they are not integers, it will complicate the function.